# Loop through Java Object inside jQuery using Thymeleaf template

Tags: java, jquery, thymeleaf

I am new to Java and thymeleaf. Using jquery and thymeleaf, I have tried to generate html rows dynamically.

Is it somehow possible to loop through thymeleaf tags inside the jquery function? (Because Thymeleaf is a server-side template engine for java)

If not, how can I loop through `facilities` variable inside jquery.

**Controller : ProjectController.java**

```
@GetMapping("/create")
public String create(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("project", new Project());
    model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.getAllCategories());
    model.addAttribute("features", featureService.getAllFeatures());
    model.addAttribute("facilities", facilityService.getAllFacilities());
    model.addAttribute("investors", investorService.getAllInvestors());

    return CREATE_PAGE;
}
```

**View : create.html**

```
 $("#add-new-row").on('click', function () {
        var html = "";

        html += `<tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="facilities[][id]" class="form-control">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Select facility</option>
                            <option th:each="facility : [(  ${facilities} )]" th:value="${facility.id}" th:text="${facility.name}"></option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" step="any" name="facilities[][distance]"
                               placeholder="Distance (Km)"
                               class="form-control">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning remove-current-row"><i
                                class="fa fa-times"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>`;

        $("#append-new-facility").append(html);
    });

    $(document).on('click', ".remove-current-row", function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
```

**View**

**Here the list of facilities is supposed to be dynamic and is received as an array of objects.**

[image]

**Error**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: facility is not defined
```

Please mention if the question needs some more detail. Any help would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing in facilities as an array to your JavaScript and building it in Jquery.  There is no way to have the Thymeleaf tags parsed in JavaScript.

For example:

```
let facilities = /*[[${facilities}]]*/ [];
let select = $('<select name="facilities[][id]" class="form-control" />');
select.append('<option value="" disabled selected>Select facility</option>');
facilities.forEach(function (facility) {
  select.append($('<option></option>').attr('val', facility['id']).text(facility['name']));
});
html += $('<div>').append(select).html();
```

Comment: This is returning an empty array on variable facilities.